# Trying to Install RVM 1.8.7

Tags: macos, rvm, osx-lion

I am trying to install rvm 1.8.7. The command I am trying to use is: `rvm install 1.8.7`.

I receive this error: `rvm: command not found`

I am new to system configuration and rvm, can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am using Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion)

I have not installed rvm previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have `rvm` on your system, then follow the instructions here: [Installing RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). Basically, you have to download a shell script that will does the job for you (fetch the latest release and install it). Then, just add

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in your `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or [whatever](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed rvm already then the problem is that you don't have the path to rvm in your PATH envvar.  Include the following in your .bash_profile file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/rvm/bin/directory
```

Comment: I haven't installed rvm previously. That is what I am trying to do.